# Return type errors for function chaining in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, method-chaining, typescript-types

I'm new to TypeScript and currently migrating my JS to it.
I have some utility functions that may return different types based on its input.
I have created this example:

```js
class MyElement {
    element: HTMLElement;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this.element = element;
    }
    html(html: string | true = true): string | MyElement {
        if (html === true) {
            return this.element.innerHTML;
        } else {
            this.element.innerHTML = html;
            return this;
        }
    }
    style(prop: string, value: string) {
        this.element.style.setProperty(prop, value);
        return this;
    }
}

var el = new MyElement(document.getElementById('myID'));
el.html('Lorem Ipsum').style('color', 'red');
```

Although the return value of el.html() will definitely be MyElement the Compiler throws the error:

```
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'string | MyElement'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'string'. ts(2339)
```

How can i remove this error while still allowing me to chain the methods?

I have thought of seperating the methods but that would result in a lot of functions.

Comment: Technically, the way to declare what you have here is with overloads. However, I think the better way is to *not* do that because the API for that  `html()` method is pretty bad. It uses [a flag argument](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html) and does *drastically* different things based on it. You can see that you literally have two completely different methods implemented into one. There is no overlap. The better option is to separate them into what they are supposed to do. Then you have no need for overloads to have the correct interface.

Comment: Looks like overloading is exactly what I need. I am also not completely fine with this approach but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I was able to solve it by using function overloading:

```js
class MyElement {
    element: HTMLElement;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    html(html: string): MyElement;
    html(html: true): string;

    html(html: string | true = true): string | MyElement {
        if (html === true) {
            return this.element.innerHTML;
        } else {
            this.element.innerHTML = html;
            return this;
        }
    }
    style(prop: string, value: string) {
        this.element.style.setProperty(prop, value);
        return this;
    }
}

var el = new MyElement(document.getElementById('myID'));
el.html('Lorem Ipsum').style('color', 'red');
```